# Type convertion in VB.NET on Windows Mobile

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-mobile, type-conversion

I am maintaining an application for a Barcode-scanner running Windows Mobile with .NET 2.0 SP 1 and VB.NET. The application integrates with an Oracle database using PL/SQL.

I have a SQL-query that returns a DataTable with list of items to be picked with the scanner, and sometimes the quantity is a decimal number.

The problem is that I can't convert a decimal number such as 0,8 from string to double. I have tried all of the following:

```
Dim quantity As String = "0,8"
Dim result As Double = Convert.ToDouble(quantity)
Dim result As Double = Double.Parse(quantity)
Dim result As Double = CDbl(quantity)
```

In all cases the result is 8 and not 0,8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `CurrentCulture` has `.` as decimal separator and you're trying to parse value with `,` instead.

Try that:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Current.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ","
Dim result As Double = Double.Parse(quantity)
```

Comment: There is no `Thread.Current.CurrentCulture` in the Compact Framework.

Comment: Exactly. No CurrentCulture in CF! I played a bit around with separators the code and SQL, and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

The CF is limited in it's ability to parse. I assume the device culture is set to en-US, in which case you could do something like this:

```
Dim quantity As String = "0,8"
Dim result As Double = Double.Parse(quantity.Replace(',', '.'))
```

If you wanted it to be more locale-aware as far as the device's current setting, you could be more safe with something like this:

```
Dim quantity As String = "0,8"
Dim result As Double

If CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator == "."
    result = Double.Parse(quantity.Replace(',', '.'))
Else
    result = Double.Parse(quantity)
End If
```